# HMSET and field value

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I am utterly confused about HMSET.

If I create a HMSET with 'N' number of (field value)... pairs then

1. Can I access the values in the 'field' in O(1) time ? ( The documentation says "Time complexity: O(N) where N is the number of fields being requested." ). so accessing one field should be O(1). Does it behave just like a dictionary ? is that assumption correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - Hashes exhibit O(1) complexity when accessing a single field.